# Discord.py def check_queue to send message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Can not use `await` in `def check_queue`.
To use `await` you need to use `def` or `async`.
How to write `await` without using `async` or
Could you tell me another way?

```
def check_queue(id):
if queues[id] != []:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Next Music")
    player = queues[id].pop(0)
    players[id] = player
    player.start()
```

Comment: Why? You should be writing all of your asynchronous code in coroutines (`async def` functions) so that it can run in the event loop with your bot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the asynchronous way that's what you need to do.

```
// works only inside async functions
let value = await promise;
```

e.g.

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```

If you try to use await in non-async function, that would be a syntax error:

```
function f() {
  let promise = Promise.resolve(1);
  let result = await promise; // Syntax error
}
```

Source: https://javascript.info/async-await

Check [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/avoiding-the-async-await-hell-c77a0fb71c4c) JS post. Might be useful to you.

Same principles apply to Python. You could use either async/await or yield from. However, if you use either from within a non asynchronous function will get you a Syntax error.

And [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/) is a Python post that will give you a good understanding of how you should implement it.

And here is a simple example of how it should be done:

```
import asyncio


async def io_related(name):
    print(f'{name} started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'{name} finished')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        io_related('first'),
        io_related('second'),
    )  # 1s + 1s = over 1s


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Outputs:

```
first started
second started
first finished
second finished
```